# Is it possible to write yaml pipeline script where a build stage having one job related to master branch and another job related to publish branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

On writing the yaml script the artifacts are being published but both the drops contain files that are in our master branch. Do we have any options to do so as the yaml pipeline is being created in master branch.

***I want to write a yaml pipeline script where i will publish artifacts from master branch and from adf_publish branch and use the drop that is created once the artifact is build to further build another stage for deployment.***

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
  
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Second, deploy based on the artifact of build pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Artifacts is generated but empty.

Comment: To elaborate more on my question, I have a folder in my branch a and another folder in branch b. Now, I want to write a yaml pipeline script where I will be adding task to publish artifacts. One artifacts will published with folder in branch a and the other artifacts will be published with folder in branch b.

Comment: branch master - pre-post deployment script
adf_publish- templateparameters.json
template.json
Yaml pipeline - I want to publish artifact where 1 folder will contain folder from master branch and the other branch will contain folder from adf_publish branch.